# Solving 2nd order ODE with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, legendre-polynomials, wavelets

**ODE:**

$$X''(t)+A(t)X'(t)+B(t)X(t)=F(t),$$

**IC's:** $$X(0)=U_1,  $$
$$X'(0)=U_2$$

where

$X(t)=[X_1 X_2...X_n]^T$ and $U_1, U_2,F(t)$ are $n\times1$ matrices,

$A(t), B(t)$ are $n\times n$ matrices.

**Question:** How to solve the 2nd order ODE with variable coefficients by Legendre Wavelets?

(I know to solve 2nd order ODE with constant coefficients by Legendre Wavelets. But I can' t solve the ODE with variable coefficients)

**My try:**
Let $X''(t)=C^T \Psi(t).$

Then we take integral from $0$ to $t$, we have

$X'(t)=C^T P \Psi(t)+X'(0)=C^T P \Psi(t)+\bar{C}_0^T \Psi(t)$

where $\int_{0}^{t}C^T \Psi(\hat{t})d\hat{t}=C^T P \Psi(t)$ and $X'(0)=\bar{C}_0^T \Psi(t).$

and similarly we take integral from $0$ to $t$, we have

$X(t)=C^T P_2 \Psi(t)+\bar{C}_0^T \Psi(t)+C_0^T \Psi(t)$
where $X(0)=C_0^T \Psi(t).$

Let $A(t)=\bar{A}^T\Psi(t) $ and $B(t)=\bar{B}^T\Psi(t) $ and $F(t)=\bar{F}^{T}\Psi(t). $

Substituting to all above equations to ODE, we have
$$C^T \Psi(t)+\bar{A}^T\Psi(t)\big(C^T P \Psi(t)+\bar{C}_0^T \Psi(t)\big)+\bar{B}^T \Psi(t)\big(C^T P_2 \Psi(t)+\bar{C}_0^T \Psi(t)+C_0^T \Psi(t)\big)=\bar{F}^{T}\Psi(t) $$

Is it right? And then?

Comment: Now you need to apply the connection coefficients for the multiplication, $Ψ_i(t)Ψ_j(t)=\Gamma^k_{ij}Ψ_k(t)$. Then compare coefficients, etc.